# How to remove the caption "Figure" from the Table of figures in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, table-of-contents, caption

In my thesis, I have the following table of figures (it's in French): [image: Table of figures - extract].

As you can see the expression "Figure" is repeated throughout the table ("Figure 1.1", "Figure 1.2", etc.). However, according to my college's visual requirements for publishing theses, I have to delete the repeated caption "Figure" in my Table of contents.

How could I do that without manually deleting the word "Figure" line by line, or altering the body text?

Here is the final result that I want: [image: Table of figure - extract (Desired)].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Table of Figures in Word is a type of Table of Contents. It is actually the same field.
By default, it picks up whatever is in the Caption style in your document. That style is used when you insert a caption.

To remove the word "Figure" from your Table of Figures entries, you need to remove it from the Captions, themselves. It may be possible to have appear to be in the captions but that is going to require a [Style Separator](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Style_Separator).

This is not simple but can be done. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

**Here is a [temporary link to a document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqxdhbq9hn42zu9/split%20caption%20example.docx?dl=0) with this done.**

**Prior to doing this:**

- Turn *on* display of non-printing formatting characters.

**Steps that have to be applied to each caption:**

1. The Caption needs to be split into two paragraphs after the word “Figure” by
   pressing the enter key. So press Enter.
2. To the first paragraph containing the word “Figure” the paragraph
   style CaptionFalse was applied. This is a custom style based on Body
   Text but with the font formatting of the Caption Style. It is NOT
   based on the Caption style. You will need to create the CaptionFalse style the first time you do this. *(You can choose your own name if you want.)*
3. The paragraph mark at the end of that paragraph is selected and
   marked with the font formatting of hidden. This can be done by
   selecting just the paragraph mark and pressing Ctrl+Shift+H to mark
   it as hidden. Otherwise, this is in the Format Font dialog. This turns the paragraph mark into a "[style separator](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Style_Separator)."

**After you have finished altering all of your captions...**

1. Turn *off* display of non-printing formatting marks. This display may change your pagination.
2. When the Table of Figures is created or updated, it picks up the
   text in the Caption style but ignores that in the CaptionFalse
   Style. Update your Table of Figures.

Comment: Thank you Charles for your quick answer!

If that's not to much of a burden, I'd be happy to have the sample document you're offering! That would allow me to use it, but also to share it with my college's librarians who are responsible for keeping updated our Word template for essays and theses.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link. This is covered, although not in as much depth, in my page on complex documents. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#part_of_a_heading

Comment: So ingenious! Thank you so much Charles! I learned today what are hidden characters and how to use them for my thesis.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.